# Is there a way to check if SSL v3 is enabled/disabled in android browser

Tags: tls, openssl

I would like to check if my browsers SSL v3 is enabled or disabled. The concern is, if I know that the SSL v3 is enabled then I will try to disable it and check to see if I am able to visit the websites which only uses SSL v3 or not.

Like how [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html) say that the browser I use is using TLS 1.2, in the same way I want to know if this also uses SSL v3 or not.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't you just answer your own question? :)

Comment: Yup. On the SSL Labs page just scroll down to the "Protocol Features" section.

Comment: Oh yea :) even before I saw this comment I found it myself.
Safari - supports SSLv3 and Chrome does not :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's two client test sites.

- Just about SSL3: https://zmap.io/sslv3/sslv3test.html
- Comprehensive: SSL Labs (that you already mentioned yourself). You need to scroll down to the "Protocol Features" section: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html